# Reading a text file from a jar

Tags: java, file, text, jar

I'm having trouble reading a text file from inside a jar. I managed it while it was unzipped but now that I've archived it it won't work.
The jar has:

- BTA.jar

  - Splash.class
  - *.class
  - Splash.txt
  - etc..

Now, at the moment I'm using a BufferedReader and a FileReader

```
 f = new FileReader("Splash.txt");
 in = new BufferedReader(f);
```

but from googling around I know that that only reads files from outside of the jar.

My question is: How do I read a file from inside the jar?

Comment: Are you running a `main` method inside `Spash` ?

Comment: No, the `main` method is in a class called `Main`

Comment: "now that I've archived it" <-- what do you mean by that? Is it part of the build process? If yes, is this archive (jar, zip) part of the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're executing the `BTA.jar`, you can use

```
InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Splash.txt");
```

to retrieve an `InputStream` and pass it to the `BufferedReader` through an `InputStreamReader`.

The rules for the format of the path to pass to the method are defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), in the javadoc for the `Class` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Splash.txt` isn't a file, its series of bytes within in a (lightly) compressed file which has a named entry within a table of contents as specified by the Jar/Zip standard.

This measn you can use `FileReader` to read the file, instead, you need to access it via the `Class` resource management API, for example..

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Splash.txt");
```

Or, if you're trying to read it from `static` context

```
Splash.class.getResourceAsStream("/Splash.txt");
```

Don't forget, you become responsible for closing the `InputStream` when you are done, for example...

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Splash.txt")) {....
```

Answer (score 0):

A jar is just a zip file and can be read like this..

```
ZipFile file = new ZipFile("/home/Desktop/myjar.jar");
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();

while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

    if (entry.getName().startsWith("splash")) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(entry)))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```